# How do I add HTML to my module's custom admin page?

Tags: 7, hooks, routes

I have set up a new page in my admin for my module like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function scraper_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['admin/scraper'] = array(
        'title' => 'Scraper',
        'description' => 'The main action page in the admin area where we control our scrapers.',
        'page callback' => 'scraper_page',
        'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
}

/**
* Page callback: Scraper page
*
* @see scraper_menu()
*/
function scraper_page() {
    return '<p>Hello world</p>';
}
```

When I navigate to admin/scraper I get the following error:

Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /######/includes/form.inc on line 1079

So how do I create a custom HTML page in the admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have tried is the right way to do. I have checked the same code snippet and its working for me in my D7 installation. Hopefully the issue will be with some other form element (probably custom block ) that has be assigned in this page, might have some syntax error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function scraper_page() {
  return array(
    '#markup' => '<p>Hello world</p>'
  );
}
```

try that.